# GROUP BY sentence in ExecuteSOQL within a Flow builder

Tags: soql, query, flow-builder

I realized that I can use ExecuteSOQL to run a SOQL query within a flow. It works perfect. But when I use a SUM() and Group By sentence, the flow display ***Invalid interview state*** after the *screen 01*, so I'm not able to see *screen 02*[image: Flow with ExecuteSOQL action. The error is displayed after screen 01]

*This only applies when Group By is in the query, otherwise, it works fine.

Any Ideas how to fix this?

Action Get Records looks like this:
[image: Action]

**Edit, var_query contains something like this:
`"SELECT Date__c, SUM(Hours__c) FROM Revenue_Forecast__c Where Opportunity__r.IsClosed = true and (Opportunity__c='xxxx' or Project__c='yyyyy') group by Date__c"`

Comment: does the doc state that aggregate queries are supported?

Comment: You're right! It seems, aggregate queries are not supported yet :(   Thank you!!

Comment: what does your invocable apex class look like? It can certainly do aggregate queries; the issue is more on how it returns results to the Flow; see for example: https://unofficialsf.com/salesforce-lightning-flow-using-advanced-soql/

Comment: I don't have apex class. I'm running this flow from a button in a Page Layout.

Comment: sorry - the Action icon confused me as I thought it was invocable Apex; use [edit] to expose the Action element and how it is configured

Comment: Updated @cropredy.

Comment: sorry, I must be dense - where's the doc for this ExecuteSOQL Apex Action?

Comment: Here you are: https://github.com/alexed1/LightningFlowComponents/tree/master/flow_action_components/ExecuteSOQLQuery

Answer (score 1):

ExecuteSOQL is an open source contribution to the Lightning Flow Community that is a LWC + invocable Apex class

The invocable Apex class at its heart takes the incoming SOQL string and does

```
List<SObject> queryResult = Database.query(soqlQuery);
```

and passes back the sobjects to the Flow.

If `soqlQuery` is an aggregate query, then the return is a list of `AggregateResult` objects.

`AggregateResult` extends `SObject` and the ExecuteSOQL component allows you to choose `AggregateResult` as the value for `Object for SObjects` input field in the UI. Do not use `Revenue Forecast` as the SOQL doesn't return `Revenue Forecast`

If you run in debug, you can see the field names in the `AggregateResult` sobject collection. Unless you use aliases in your SOQL, the `SUM(Hours__c)` will have field name of `expr0`.

You can read more about [processing `AggregateResult` objects in the Apex doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm?search_text=aggregateresult)

Comment: Great! Thank you  @cropredy !  Yes, I'm able to see the the result of SUM(Hours__c) in expr0 when debugging. However,  when I click next on "Screen 01", then it display the message Invalid interview state, with no debug messages.

Comment: Yes.  This is where things might go haywire in Flow because Flow likes to deal with sobjectTypes where static describes can be done to get field names.  AggregateResult is in effect a dynamic describe. Is there a reason you can't write your own apex invocable to return the sum in a custom apex type?

Comment: Yes, the reason is that I don't know how to do it, haha... Ok, that makes sense! I'll figure it out. Thank you so much!